# Calculating ionic strength at different concentrations

Tags: ionic-compounds, rate-equation, reaction-order

> Zn$^{2+}$ reacts with a molecule, B, in a solution at several different concentrations of NaCl.
>
> Determine the charge of the biomolecule and k$_0$ (second order) ​​(assume that Zn$^{2+}$ does not change the state of charge)
>
> The pH is adjusted with HCl
>
> [ZnCl$_2$]$_0$ = $1$ mM
>
> pH = $3.0$
>
> [B]$_0$ = $\pu{1.40e-6}$ M
>
> The concentrations of B at different concentrations of NaCl are:
> $$
> \begin{array}{lr}
> \hline
> \text{time}/\pu{min} & \ce{NaCl}/ \pu{50mM} & \ce{NaCl}/ \pu{75mM} & \ce{NaCl}/ \pu{100mM}\\
> \hline
> 1 & \pu{1.39e-6}& \pu{1.38e-6} & \pu{1.37e-6}\\
> 2 & \pu{1.37e-6} & \pu{1.35e-6}& \pu{1.33e-6}\\
> 3 & \pu{1.36e-6} & \pu{1.33e-6}& \pu{1.30e-6}\\
> 4 & \pu{1.34e-6} & \pu{1.31e-6}& \pu{1.27e-6}\\
> 5 & \pu{1.33e-6} & \pu{1.29e-6}& \pu{1.24e-6}\\
> \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

I began by calculating the rate constants for each concentration of NaCl (converted in M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$) and got:

k$_{50}$ = $135$ M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$

k$_{75}$ = $206$ M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$

k$_{100}$ = $314$ M$^{-1}$s$^{-1}$

I then know I should calculate the ionic strength of each concentration in order to then be able to plot $\log (k)$ against I$^{1/2}$. However, I am confused as to how to calculate the ionic strength given B$_0$. If B$_0$ was not given then I would have calculated the ionic strength as:

$I = \frac12 \sum z^2(b_i/b_0) = \frac12 \left( 2^2 \cdot \ce{[Zn^2^+]}^2]+ (-1)^2 \cdot \ce{[Cl-]} + 1^2 \cdot \ce{[Na+]} + (-1)^2 \cdot \ce{[Cl-]} \right)$

Which would give me the answers:

$I_{50} = \frac12 ( 2^2 \cdot (\pu{1e-3})+ (-1)^2 \cdot (\pu{2e-3}) + 1^2 \cdot 0.05 + (-1)^2 \cdot 0.05) = 0.053$

$I_{75} = \frac12 ( 2^2 \cdot (\pu{1e-3})+ (-1)^2 \cdot (\pu{2e-3}) + 1^2 \cdot 0.075 + (-1)^2 \cdot 0.075) = 0.078$

$I_{100} = \frac12( 2^2 \cdot (\pu{1e-3})+ (-1)^2 \cdot (\pu{2e-3}) + 1^2 \cdot 0.1 + (-1)^2 \cdot 0.1) = 0.13$

These would then be plotted as $\log(k)$ against I$^{1/2}$. But what is the B$_0$ for then? I would assume that it should be incorporate into the calculation of the ionic strength somehow but I don't understand how.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the equation of the reaction ? What is the unit of the given numerical values in the table ? Is the ion Cl- included in the reaction ? Why do you calculate the ionic strength ? Is the concentration not sufficient ? What is the meaning of NaCl/50 mM ? Does it mean that the concentration of NaCl is 50 mM ? What is the difference between Bo and bo ?

Comment: @Maurice The equation of the reaction is not given. The values are the concentration of B thus I would assume they are in the unit M (it is not specified). I want to calculate the ionic strength so that I can determine k$_0$ from the equation logk = logk$_0$ + $1.02$z$_A$z$_B$$^{1/2}$. Yes, sorry it means that the concentration of NaCl is $50$,$75$ and $100$. B$_0$ is the initial concentration of B while b$_i$ is the molality of the ion and b$_0$ is the standard state $1$ mol kg$^{-1}$.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your question. I would assume that since the concentration of the biomolecule is so low it does not affect the ionic strength. It should be easy to test whether this affects the result. The $B_0$ provide additional data points for the fits (at time 0, presumably in the determination of k).

Comment: Are you sure of your formula $\pu{log k = log k_o + 1.02 z_A√z_B }$ ? I suppose that $z$ is the charge of the ion. This formula shows that $ k$ does not change with the concentration and the ionic strength...

Comment: @Maurice Sorry, an "I" is missing in the equation: logk=logk$_0$+$1.02$z$_A$z$_B$√I